# .htaccess 301 redirect active - Yet Google Analytics (Realtime) shows many active visitors on the old site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, google-analytics

As the title says, I am redirecting example.me to example.com. Here's my .htaccess in example.me:

```
# DESKTOP #
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# DISABLE IFRAME #
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

# REDIRECT #
RewriteRule $ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Yet, Google Analytics and even Google Analytics Realtime shows about 20% of the traffic still accesses the old (example.me) domain. Why is this? Is it an error from Google or are these people really on the old site?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this. Old Faithful.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I used this code, doesn't help. There are still visitors on the old site (according to Google Analytics).

Comment: Is it possible that you may have some squatting going on? Have these numbers fluctuated or are the staying the same?

Comment: Numbers are staying the same, day for day. About 20% of the traffic. From all over the world. Really strange...